# Split html into multiple files using nodejs

Tags: html, node.js

I'm experimenting on Nodejs and have a requirement to split a large html file based on a tag. The source html is actually a combination of multiple html documents and I need to split this and process each document separately. This is not for any webpage. It is for actual document printing to pdf.

The input file looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><HPDPSMsg>
<DocumentRequest>
<MetaData><DocumentLanguage>E
<Report ReportName =".................
<FirstPageHeaderDetails>....................
</Sections></Report></DocumentRequest>
<DocumentRequest>
<MetaData><DocumentLanguage>E
<Report ReportName =".................
<FirstPageHeaderDetails>....................
</Sections></Report></DocumentRequest>
```

And I would like this split into 2 files based on the DocumentRequest tag.

Can anyone point me to a suitable nodejs library that I can use? I have looked at libraries like pub but they don't have any split function.

Comment: You can create new js files and export html string then in main page require that files. [example](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/nodejs-module-exports)

Comment: You would probably need something like a html parser (e.g: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-html-parser). Basically you assign your html to a variable and then use other functions to target the element or the selector.